# How can I go from hosting locally to being internet accessable?

Tags: networking, server

I have a server that is hosting a "shiny" app using shiny-server. I can host locally where my address looks like:

```
http://charles-p-7805u:3838/histogram/
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:3838/histogram/
```

How can I make this hosted on the internet?  Sorry for the general and possibly vague question but I'm not very educated.  My intuition says that I could have others connect to my IP and port if I could make them public.  Is this incorrect?

Thanks a bunch. Working with 12.04.  Please ask for any clarification if I missed any important details to mention.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First thing it to check if you have class A IP address. Just go to this address and note down our ip. [http://ipaddress.com](http://ipaddress.com/)

Also look for ifconfig output. Both addresses should be the same.
If yout ip does not start with 172, 10 ,192 then you are ready to go. From a diffrent computer or from your phone just enter http:/*yourip*:3838/histogram/
If you have an class C ip address then you must have access to your router / gateway and make an port fowarding.

Comment: I'm using a router but I have an IP starting in 66.  When I try to connect from another computer (on the same router) it says it is unable to connect.  If I just pulled this router out of the box a couple weeks ago is there something I need to do?

Comment: With an external ip you should connect to it using an external computer, not in the same lan (use your phone). If it does not work, just to test, insert the internet cable directly into the server and see if it is a firewall issue.

Comment: There is no such thing as "class A" or "class C" addresses anymore. There has not been for [25 years](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1519). These terms should never be used anymore, except when discussing the pre-1993 historical Internet. And the "class", even if it still existed, did not then and does not now have any relevance to whether one can host a server on that IP address.